# Cannot set image source angular js

Tags: angularjs

The `ng-src` tag does not get value, and also get error. Please give me solution

Controller:

```
for(var i =1 ;i<=5; i++){
   $scope["ValueField" + i] = i;
   $scope["PerformanceStatusImage" + i] = "../CSS/down-icn.png";
}
```

HTML:

```
<tr >
   <td ng:repeat="id in [1,2,3,4,5]">
       <label ng-bind="ValueField{{id}}"></label>
        <img ng-src ="{{PerformanceStatusImage{{id}}}}" ></img>
   </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Instead of four variables you can use single array

Comment: problem is to evaluate double expression inside ng-src

Comment: Error: [$parse:lexerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.14/$parse/lexerr?p0=Unterminated%20quote&p1=s%2022-27%20%5B'%7B%7Bid%5D&p2=PerformanceStatusImage'%7B%7Bid
M/<@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js:6:417

Comment: Yes correct, How I evaluate double expression inside ng-src?

Comment: I want to know why you want to use double expression

Answer (score 0):

You are taking PerformanceStatusImage1,PerformanceStatusImage2,PerformanceStatusImage3,PerformanceStatusImage4  different objects, where you need one to perform iteration

For example:-

HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="Image in Images">
  <img ngsrc='{{Image}}'/>
</div>
```

Angularjs

```
app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope){
    $scope.Images=[];
       for(var i =1 ;i<=5; i++){ 
       $scope.Images[i] = "../CSS/down-icn.png"; 
    }
});
```

Comment: HI shubham Nigam, Please find the edited question, looking forward your support